# Como colocar dois planos de fundo na mesma pagina?

Tags: css

Eu estou criando uma pagina em HTML com CSS, e gostaria de saber como colocar dois planos de fundo na mesma pagina HTML via CSS. Eu tenho essa imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu quero colocar essa imagem no top, só que a altura dela não é suficiente pra cobrir a página inteira, então eu quero colocar um linear-gradient(to bottom, #000,#CCC) a partir de onde essa imagem acaba, pra dar um efeito legal, mas não consigo fazer isso.

Comment: Pode por favor especificar que tipo de planos de fundo?

Comment: Onde , no body?

Comment: A solução deste site é ótima para fazer o que precisa: http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/ $.vegas('slideshow', { delay:15000, backgrounds:[ { src:'images/2.jpg', fade:1000 }, { src:'images/6.jpg', fade:1000 } ] })('overlay');

Comment: Sim no body, eu quero colocar uma imagem no top, dae em baixo dessa imagem um linear-gradient...eu tentei colocar mas nao deu muito certo

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Se você não tiver restrição de compatibilidade entre browsers, com **CSS3** isso seria possível, já que ele aceita múltiplos backgrounds em um único elemento:

```
body{
    background-image: url(imagem1.png), url(imagem2.png), url(imagem3.png);
}
```

Lembrando que essa funcionalidade também funciona com gradientes em CSS3:

```
body{
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255,0,0,0.1),rgba(0,255,0,0.1)),
                      linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,0,0.1), rgba(0,255,255,0.1));
}
```

---

De acordo com o site [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multibackgrounds), a compatibilidade dos principais browsers para essa funcionalidade é:

**IE9+** *(não suporta gradientes)*, **Chrome**, **Firefox**, **Opera**, **Safari (iOS) 3.2+**, **Android 2.1+**

Comment: Como faço para definir a posição de cada background? Por que eles estão ficando um sobre o outro....

Comment: ```background-position:x(px) y(px), x(px) y(px)```, exemplo: ```background-position:100px 200px, 200px 300px```

Comment: vlw kra, deu certo aqui!